# Why got I message incorrect syntax near 'SOURCE'?

Tags: mysql

I get error:

> SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near 'SOURCE'.

```
DROP TABLE license_assignments;

SOURCE ./DW-1423-license-assignment/license_assignments.SQL
```

How fix it?

> Unexpected symbol '/' (U+002F)

Answer (score 1):

Because you try to run MySql CLI command as MySql query.

Check [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html) it's usage

---

`source ./DW-1423-license-assignment/license_assignments.SQL` is same as `mysql db_name < ./DW-1423-license-assignment/license_assignments.SQL`.

It can't be executed as SQL command.